# Angular - form validators don't work on initial load

Tags: angular, validation

I need the error to show up on the initial load. Instead it only shows after typing something in the textarea. How do I force the validators error to appear on the initial load indicating that text is required?

HTML:

```
<epc-textarea class="half spaced-content" label="Description" formControlName="description" [maxlength]="descLength">
     <div class="error" *ngIf="_description.errors?.required" required>{{requiredMsg}}</div>
</epc-textarea>
```

TS:

```
description: ['', [Validators.required]]
```

Comment: validation as it's name says validate the input data from user, so when user didn't input anything what should be validate?!! for warn user that description is required you can simply mark it with * (is a common mark for required input and add text that shows * field is required) or just place text such as "this field is required" in input placeholder.

Comment: if you has  `get _description(){return this.form.get('description')}` must work. IT's true that in material the mat-error only show if the input is touched, but in normal inputs should work. (I don't know about your `epc-textarea` and perhafs you need write a `this.form.markAllAsTouched()`

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I did have **"get _description(){return this.form.get('description')}** and tried **this.form.markAllAsTouched()** also tried **this.Form.controls['description'].markAsTouched();** None if this works, because I have material Mat-error. Those elements only work if touched. Instead I just removed the validation from the "Description" component. and put it as a separate element: '<div class="flex-row">
      <div class="half spaced-content"></div>
      <div class="half justified-space" *ngIf="_description.errors?.required">{{requiredMsg}}</div>
    </div>'